# SJoin CRS warning causing function to hang - Python

Tags: python, warnings, distance, spatial, geopandas

I've encountered an issue that I cannot get to the bottom of using sjoin.nearest with Geopandas.  I import a suburb shapefile (polgyons) which loads using the 7844 CRS.  I then create a dataframe from two points, setting to the 3112 CRS which is recommended in the documentation for a correct metric system result.  I then attempt to measure the distance from the points to the nearest polygon (despite mismatched geometries) - this yields the correct result when run from the IDE but will not return any result inside the function (I have set the suburb to print after the sjoin), instead causing it to hang until I press CTRL+C - which then prints the suburb in my IDE.

I have tried multiple ways to suppress warnings, but even when suppressed the issue still persists.  The warning I get is a UserWarning quoting the mismatch in CRS.  However, when I set both to 3112, thus producing no error or hang in the code, the polygon shapes all appear multiplied out by 1000 and the suburb match is completely wrong.

I am running the function from within a thread, in case that makes any difference, thoguh the suburb geodataframe is loaded at the beginning of the script, outside the thread (have tried loading it inside with same issue)

I've included the code below and the warning suppression stuff I tried. Any help would be very much appreciated! Maybe it's an issue with Geopandas? Or maybe I just need a new way to measure distnces in this case (a shame as this has been very convenient for me in previous scripts)

**Code (runs in IDE, not in full script/function):**

```
suburbFeather = geofeather.from_geofeather(os.path.join(geoShpFldr, 'suburb.feather'))

Point = pd.DataFrame({'x': [145.04241], 'y': [-37.77216]})
Point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(propPoint, crs="EPSG:3112", geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(propPoint['x'], propPoint['y']))
Point = propPoint.to_crs(3112)

suburb = gpd.sjoin_nearest(propPoint.iloc[[0]][['geometry']], suburbFeather, distance_col="dist").suburbName.values[0]
```

---

I have tried a few things I've found online to suppress warnings, though even with warnings suppressed the issue persists. Here are some examples however, in case useful:

```
import warnings
import logging
import sys
```

Tried each of the below separately

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
warnings.warn("ignore", UserWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings(action = 'ignore')
```

Tried this in the lines before and after the line thaty causes the issue

```
logging.captureWarnings(True)
logging.captureWarnings(False)
```

Tried below in the same manner as logging above

```
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")  # silence stderr
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__  # unsilence stderr
```

Tried this which creates a lock

```
def fxn():
    warnings.warn("ignore", UserWarning)  ## ("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with lock_for_purpose:
     print("lock is done")       
     with warnings.catch_warnings():
         warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
         fxn()
         suburb = gpd.sjoin_nearest(propPoint.iloc[[0]][['geometry']], suburbFeather, distance_col="dist").suburbName.values[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as a **geopandas** issue as such.  Have re-generated a repeatable MWE that will create warning you are trying to suppress.

This works exactly as expected.  Warning is suppressed.  Now what you don't state is any details of your runtime environment.  Is it multi-threaded?  Using a context manager should be safe in this way.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import warnings

# question notes many polygons
gdfpoly = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# question notes a few points
gdfpoint = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities')).sample(2, random_state=42)

# this will generate the warning as Geometry is in a geographic CRS
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=UserWarning)
    gdfr = gdfpoly.sjoin_nearest(gdfpoint)

gdfr.sample(5, random_state=42)
```

|  | pop_est | continent | name_left | iso_a3 | gdp_md_est | geometry | index_right | name_right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 1.64865e+07 | Asia | Cambodia | KHM | 27089 | POLYGON ((102.5849324890267 12.186594956 | 95 | Tbilisi |
| 116 | 2.65764e+06 | Europe | Moldova | MDA | 11968 | POLYGON ((26.619336785597795 48.22072622 | 95 | Tbilisi |
| 58 | 8.08237e+06 | Africa | Togo | TGO | 5490 | POLYGON ((0.8995630224740694 10.99733938 | 15 | Juba |
| 101 | 2.86087e+07 | Asia | Nepal | NPL | 30641 | POLYGON ((88.12044070836987 27.876541652 | 95 | Tbilisi |
| 141 | 6.02974e+07 | Europe | Italy | ITA | 2003576 | MULTIPOLYGON (((10.44270145024663 46.893 | 95 | Tbilisi |